# In Java, how to compare two object and return Map or Xml, Json of properties which is the difference between two object?

Tags: java

In Java, how to compare two object and return Map or Xml, Json of properties which is the difference between two object ?
Example :
I have object 1 :

```
public class User {

    public String username = "1";
     public String password = "1";

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

and object 2 :

```
public class User {

    public String username = "2";
     public String password = "2";

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

when ObjectUtils.compare(object1,object2); --> return HashMap contain "username" and "passwork" as key

Comment: Depends on what you mean by difference. You mean like if two objects have a field x, one is x=10 and one is x=12, then the output would be "x:2"?

Comment: I don't care about difference between value, i just want to return [x] in your case

Comment: This is pretty vaguely stated, and could really use an example of input objects and desired result.

Comment: If you meant comparing arbitrary objects and finding the differences, could you please share the approach or the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an "object diff" for me. If you only have one specific class you would like to compare, you could simply write your own comparison logic. If you require a more generic approach for arbitrary classes, then there are [tools which use reflection](https://github.com/OliverStuch/jodt) to do this kind of object comparison.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by comparing objects?

1. To compare Object references you can use `a==b`.
2. To compare Object values use `a.equals(b)`
3. Other that that you can use 2 methods from `Comparable & Comparator interface` that are `a.compareTo(b)` and `compare(a,b)`